# Magento 2 : Save Custom Attribute to sales_orders Table

Tags: magento2, customer, sales-order, custom-attributes

I have added a custom attribute for storing additional emails for customers.

By default, when an order is placed, the **customer_email** field in *sales_order* table is taking from the **email** field from *customer_entity*. However, I need the customer_email field to use my custom attribute.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do following thins.

1. Use `"sales_order_place_after"` event in your custom extension.
2. In code, get value of `customer_email` using order object and save value into your `custom_attribute` as well.

Comment: When using sales_order_place_after event, can I get my custom attribute from \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession?

Comment: You can load customer by email and used any custom attribute value of that customer associated with order.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution,

1. I use event `sales_order_place_after` in my custom module.
2. I used this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171330/magento2-get-custom-customer-attribute-value) to get my customer custom attribute and set it to `customer_email` in `sales_order` table